# How to run predict.boosting for new data?

Tags: r, prediction, adaboost

I am trying to use predict.boosting for new data in adabag package. I can't find a way to use it for data without labels (or any other function from that package).

I am trying:

```
pr <- predict.boosting(modelfit, test[,2:ncol(test)])
```

It gives:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(newdata, , as.character(object$formula[[2]])) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

However, if I include labels:

```
pr <- predict.boosting(modelfit, test)
```

it works just fine. But there has to be a way to use it as a predictive model for data without labels.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT
Example from package:

```
library(rusboost)
library(rpart)
data(iris)
```

make it an unbalanced dataset by removing most of the setosa observations

```
df <- iris[41:150,]
```

create binary variable

```
df$Setosa <- factor(ifelse(df$Species == "setosa", "setosa", "notsetosa"))
```

create index of negative examples

```
idx <- df$Setosa == "notsetosa"
```

run model

```
test.rusboost <- rusb(Setosa ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width,
                      data = df, boot = F, iters = 20, sampleFraction = .1, idx = idx)

predict.boosting(test.rusboost, df)
predict.boosting(test.rusboost, df[,1:4)
```

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provided a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks for commenting,I added one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should control that all your columns in `train` (the set you used to train the model) are present in `test` an with the same name.

Please check:

```
all(colnames(train) %in% colnames(test))
```

If it's false, you will need to control how you built train and test.

If it's TRUE, and in general, please provide a reproductible example.

**Edit:**

A nice way to control that columns are the same, and they contain the same factors is to use `sameShape` from dataPreparation package. If it's not the cas, it will add levels and columns (and warn you).

To use it:

```
library(dataPreparation)
test <- sameShape(test, train)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I checked, it gives TRUE. It only produces error when I omit the labels. I gave an example above.

Comment: Before applying your model, you can use the function `sameShape` from dataPreparation package. It will control that you have the same columns dans the same levels in them.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a workaround, I attached a column with the same name as the labels to my newdata and filled it with random factor levels.

```
df$Setosa <- factor(sample( c("setosa",  "notsetosa"), nrow(df), replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5, 0.5) ))
```

Then it works just fine.